# Intigration tawk.to with dialogflow in flutter

Tags: flutter, dialogflow-es, chatbot, tawk.to

Hi I'm having an app which has a feature of chat bot which is AI based chat bot backed with google dialogflow. But I want to add a feature which will let user chat with my backend time when user select option of chat with expert or something like that for that I'm planning to use tawk.to which free chat bot can you help me into login how can I do this or any documentation or somethig ??

Answer (score 0):

First you have to create an account on [tawk.to](https://www.tawk.to) and create specific property for you project. Then you can use [flutter_tawk](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_tawk) package for implementing **tawk.to** to your app.

Comment: Yea I checked it already but I want to find some logic about how can I send user to the tawk.to when he press contact expert in my own app.